# how to create multiple instances of the same JS object controlling separate CSS and DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, object

I am in the early phase of creating an object as a plug-in that creates and controls a set of `DIV` and `INPUT` elements. The aim is to have multiple instances doing the same, but each instance only for their own DIV and INPUT.

Part one is working fine as shown by the yellow dot in the snippet.

Now only when I create the second instance, the first one (red dot) stops working. The first object still exists and I can address and set its parameters, only the animation it should be managing has stopped. So either the eventListener to new input is not working when two objects exist or the way I initialise the object is wrong. Here I need help.

I am asking this question before I continue making the object's parser more complex as it should parse and draw more complex multiple inputs hereafter.

How do I properly separate the two controller instances?

snippet:

```js
function randomButton(button_id){
 if(button_id=='demo_1'){
  while(MyObject_1.val()==MyObject_1.rand()){} 
 }
 if(button_id=='demo_2'){
  end = MyObject_2.rand();
  start = (end-MyObject_2.rand()).toFixed(2);
  if(start<0){start=0;}
  MyObject_2.val(end+" , "+start);
 }
}

function alertObjectInfo(object){
 text = "";
    if (null == object || "object" != typeof object) return object;
    for (var attr in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(attr)) text += (object[attr]+"\n");
    } 
 alert(text);
}

/* start of of the plug-in code */
var MyPlugin = ( function (element, id) {
 
 if(id===undefined){ // if no ID is provided genetate a hex string as ID
  id = ("OBJ-"+(new Date).getTime().toString(16)+"_"+(new Date).getMilliseconds().toString(16));
 }

 element.addEventListener('change', function () {
  /* this part of the code will only run if the element input value is changed */
  parser.input = this.value;
  parser.run();
  object.draw(parser.result);
 });
 
 defaults = [];
 defaults['size'] = 24;
 defaults['radius'] = 12;
 defaults['padding'] = 4;
 defaults['bgcolor'] = 'orange';
 defaults['color'] = 'yellow';
 defaults['transition'] = '1s';
  
 /* the part below is the parser engine that converts the input  */
 parser = {
   input  : null,
   result : null,
   mode   : 'single', // default is single
   run : ( function( value ) {
    
  if(value){this.input = value;} // use value as new input if a value is provided
    
  if(this.mode==='single' || this.mode==false || this.mode===undefined){
   // parse as a single floating point value 
   this.mode = 'single'; // reset mode in case it was undefined
   this.result = parseFloat(this.input);
   if(this.result > 1){this.result = 1;}
   if(this.result < 0){this.result = 0;}
   return this.result;
  }
 
  if(this.mode==='double' || this.mode==2){
   // parse as two seperete floating point values 
   /* to be continued */
  }
 
   })
 };

 /* the code below creates an object we can talk to and that will manage sprites  */
 var object = {
   id  : id,   // optional identifier string useful for debugging
   init   : false,  // the switch to test if initialise is already done
   element   : element,  // the html element we take out input from 
   sprites : [],   // the array of sprite elements generated by this object 
   parser  : parser,  // the input parser engine
      
   /* the object's internal functions */
   draw : function() { 
  /* the main to draw and move all sprites */
  if(this.init==false){alert('error: object is not properly initialised');return false;}
  
  this.sprites[1].style.width = (this.parser.result*100)+"%";
   },
  
   show : function() { 
    /* the show all sprites function */
    element.parentNode.style.display = 'inline';
   },
   
   hide : function() { 
    /* the hide all sprites function */
    element.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
   },
   
   val : function( value ) { 
   /* the set or get value function */
     if(value===undefined){
    return element.value;
   }else{
   element.value = value;
   element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
   }
   },
   
   rand : function( maxVal, minVal, decVal ) { 
   /* create and set a random value */
     if(minVal===undefined){minVal = 0;} // default minimum value
     if(maxVal===undefined){maxVal = 1;} // default maximum value
     if(decVal===undefined){decVal = 2;} // default decimal precision
     if(maxVal < minVal){ // invert minimum and maximum if incorrect
    offVal = maxVal;
   maxVal = minVal;
   minVal = offVal;
   }
   offVal = 1; // set or reset offVal
   for (i = 0; i < decVal; i++) { 
     offVal = offVal/10;
   }
   r = (Math.random())*((maxVal+offVal)-(minVal)) + minVal;
    if(r>maxVal){r=maxVal;}
   p = Math.pow(10, decVal);
   r = Math.floor(r*p) / p;
   element.value = r;
   element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
   return r;
   },
   
   initialise : function() {

  if(this.init==false){
   /* this part will initialise everything with default values once */   
   wrapper = element.parentNode;
   
   container = document.createElement("div");
   
   container.style.backgroundColor = defaults['bgcolor'];
   container.style.height = defaults['size']+'px';
   container.style.padding = defaults['padding']+'px';
   container.style.boxSizing = 'border-box';
   
   relativeRad = (defaults['size']/2)+'px';
   container.style.borderRadius = (relativeRad+' '+relativeRad+' '+relativeRad+' '+relativeRad);
   
   wrapper.appendChild(container);
   this.sprites.push(container);
   
   mover = document.createElement("div");
   
   mover.style.backgroundColor = 'inherit';
   mover.align = 'right'; // not yet controled by defaults
   mover.style.width = '0%'; // start at 0% always
   mover.style.minWidth = (defaults['size']-(defaults['padding']*2))+'px';
   mover.style.transition = defaults['transition'];
   
   container.appendChild(mover);
   this.sprites.push(mover);
   
   sprite = document.createElement("div");

   sprite.style.backgroundColor = defaults['color'];
   sprite.style.height = (defaults['size']-(defaults['padding']*2))+'px';
   sprite.style.width = (defaults['size']-(defaults['padding']*2))+'px';
   sprite.style.minWidth = (defaults['size']-(defaults['padding']*2))+'px';
   sprite.style.display = 'block';
   sprite.style.boxSizing = 'border-box';
   
   relativeRad = (defaults['size']/3)+'px';

   sprite.style.borderRadius = (relativeRad+' '+relativeRad+' '+relativeRad+' '+relativeRad);
   sprite.style.transition = defaults['transition'];
   sprite.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
   
   mover.appendChild(sprite);
   this.sprites.push(sprite);
   
   this.init = true;
   return this.init;
  }
   }
   
 };

 object.initialise();
 return object;
 
});
/* end of of the plug-in code */


/* MyPlugin init */
var MyObject_1 = new MyPlugin(document.getElementById("demo_input_1"),'Object_1');
var MyObject_2 = new MyPlugin(document.getElementById("demo_input_2"),'Object_2');

// test if we can address sprites of the first object after creating a second object
MyObject_1.sprites[2].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

```css
.item-wrap{
 background-color: #999;
 border:0;
 border-radius: 8px;
 padding: 16px;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.demo_input{
 border:0;
 color:white;
 font-size:18px;
 padding:8px;
 background-color:transparent;
 width:100%; 
 box-sizing:border-box; 
 text-align:left
}
.item-text{
 border:0;
 color:white;
 font-size:18px;
 font-family:Avenir, Tahoma, sans-serif;
 padding-left:4px;
 padding-top:8px;
 width:100%; 
 box-sizing:border-box; 
 text-align:left
}
```

```html
<div class="item-wrap">
 <div class="item-text">
 <strong>Progress animation based on double values (Beta)</strong><br>
    <small>The first value still sends the animation to a relative point between 0 and 1. 
 The second value streches the animated sprite to an offset starting point.</small><br>
    </div>
  <div id="demo_1_wrap" class="demo">
   <input id="demo_input_2" class="demo_input" type="text" value="0 , 0">
    </div>
    <p>
      <input type="button" name="show" value="show object" onClick="MyObject_2.show()">
      <input type="button" name="hide" value="hide object" onClick="MyObject_2.hide()">
      <input style="float:right" type="button" name="alert" value="alert object" onClick="alertObjectInfo(MyObject_2)">
      <input type="button" name="rand" value="set random" id="demo_2" onClick="randomButton(this.id)">
    </p>
</div>
<div class="item-wrap">
 <div class="item-text">
 <strong>Progress animation based on a single value input</strong><br>
    <small>The input value sends the animation to a relative point between 0 and 1. 
 Empty or wrong input does nothing, where 1 or higher shows the animation at 100%</small><br>
    </div>
  <div id="demo_1_wrap" class="demo">
   <input id="demo_input_1" class="demo_input" type="text" value="0">
    </div>
    <p>
      <input type="button" name="show" value="show object" onClick="MyObject_1.show()">
      <input type="button" name="hide" value="hide object" onClick="MyObject_1.hide()">
      <input type="button" name="demo_" value="set random" id="demo_1" onClick="randomButton(this.id)">
      <input style="float:right" type="button" name="alert" value="alert object" onClick="alertObjectInfo(MyObject_1)">
    </p>
</div>
```

The expected result would be "MyObject_1" being in control of all elements within the DIV labeled ID "demo_1_wrap" and the second instance "MyObject_2" doing the same for the DIV labeled ID "demo_2_wrap".

Comment: You might start by declaring the many undeclared variables (*end*, *start*, *text*, etc.), then by reducing your code to the minimum required to display the issue.

Comment: You need to use `var` to declare `parser` as a local variable. That solves it.

Comment: I wish I could simply reduce the code by a click :-) But please explain how can undeclared or declared variables make a difference? Not all variables should be global, most of them can stay contained within the object, or not? I am learning by doing... thanks for helping....

Comment: ah, my last comment was response to RobG. Now thanks to 4castle. I will go back to the keyboard and fiddle.

Comment: You need to be a lot more careful with scoping, especially if this code will grow. When you're using a function as an object constructor you should be relying heavily on `this`. Instead of creating an object var and calling initialize on that you can attach all of these properties to your function via `this` and simply call `this.initialize(); return this`; instead of `object`. I refactored your code a bit [here](https://jsfiddle.net/627Larbq/). Some things you should try and understand are arrow functions: `() => { }` and the difference between `let` (block scoping) and `var` function scoping

Comment: Thank you so much for being so precise. It now runs well in jsfiddle so It's only fair to share the updated code. And I will soon. However in older Browsers the code throws an "Unexpected token" error at this line ```this.element.addEventListener('change', () => {``` How can this be made compatible with older versions?

Answer (score 0):

Here altered code based on some recent comments. This at the moment works with Firefox version 66, yet when using an older Browser like e.g. Safari 9.1. This code shows a syntax error at the line `this.element.addEventListener('change', () => {`

How can this last issue be solved with a bit more backward compatibility?

updated snippet:

```js
function processButton(button_id) {
  if (button_id == 'demo_1') {
    window.MyObject_1.val(window.MyObject_1.rand());
  }
  if (button_id == 'demo_2') {
    var end = MyObject_2.rand();
    var start = (end - MyObject_2.rand()).toFixed(2);
    if (start < 0) {
      start = 0;
    }
    window.MyObject_2.val(end + " , " + start);
  }
  if (button_id == 'color_2') {
    var r = window.MyObject_2.rand(0, 4096, 0).toString(16);
    window.MyObject_2.val(window.MyObject_2.val() + ' , color:#' + r);

  }
  if (button_id == 'label_2') {
    window.MyObject_2.val(window.MyObject_2.val() + ' , label:%');
    window.MyObject_2.val(window.MyObject_2.val() + ' , labelcolor:black');
  }
}
window.processButton = processButton;

function alertObjectInfo(object) {
  text = "";
  if (null == object || "object" != typeof object) return object;
  for (var attr in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(attr)) text += (object[attr] + "\n");
  }
  alert(text);
}

window.alertObjectInfo = alertObjectInfo;

/* start of of the plug-in concept code */
var MyPlugin = function(element, id) {
  this.element = element;
  if (id === undefined) { // if no ID is provided genetate a hex string as ID
    this.id = (("OBJ_" + (new Date).getTime().toString(16) + "_" + (new Date).getMilliseconds().toString(16)));
  } else {
    this.id = id;
  }

  this.element.addEventListener('change', () => {
    /* this part of the code will only run if the element input value is changed */
    this.parser.run(this.element.value);
    console.log();
    this.draw();
  });

  this.defaults = [];
  this.defaults['size'] = 30;
  this.defaults['radius'] = 30;
  this.defaults['padding'] = 5;
  this.defaults['bgcolor'] = 'orange';
  this.defaults['color'] = 'yellow';
  this.defaults['transition'] = 888; // in milliseconds

  /* the part below is the parser engine that converts the input  */
  this.parser = {
    input: null,
    result: null,
    mode: null,
    run: (function(value) {

      if (value) {
        this.input = value; // use value as new input if a value is provided
      }

      /* auto detect parser mode based on input style */
      if (this.input.indexOf("]") >= 0) {
        this.mode = 'cumulative';
      } else if (this.input.indexOf(")") >= 0) {
        this.mode = 'nested';
      } else if (this.input.indexOf(",") >= 0) {
        this.mode = 'multi';
      } else {
        this.mode = 'single';
      }

      this.result = []

      if (this.mode === 'single' || this.mode == 1 || !this.mode) {
        // parse as a single floating point value 
        this.mode = 'single'; // reset mode in case it was undefined
        this.result.push(parseFloat(this.input));
        if (this.result[0] > 1) {
          this.result[0] = 1;
        }
        if (this.result[0] < 0) {
          this.result[0] = 0;
        }
      }

      if (this.mode === 'multi' || this.mode == 2) {
        // parse as seperate floating point values 
        this.mode = 'multi'; // reset mode in case it defined as 2
        let splitted;
        splitted = this.input.split(',');
        let opt = {};
        for (var i = 0, len = splitted.length; i < len; i++) {
          if (i < 2) {
            this.result.push(parseFloat(splitted[i]));
          } else {
            // if more than 2 values the rest are option parameters
            let arr = (splitted[i]).split(':');
            let key = arr[0].trim();
            let str = arr[1].trim();
            opt[key] = str;
          }
        }
        this.result[2] = opt; // add merged options to result
      }

      if (this.mode === 'nested' || this.mode == 3) {
        // parse as seperate floating point values 
        this.mode = 'nested'; // reset mode in case it defined as 3
        let splitted;
        /* to be continued */
      }

      if (this.mode === 'cumulative' || this.mode == 4) {
        // parse as seperate floating point values 
        this.mode = 'cumulative'; // reset mode in case it defined as 4
        let splitted;
        /* to be continued */
      }

      console.log(this.result);
      return this.result;

    })
  };
  this.init = false;
  this.sprites = [];

  this.draw = () => {
    /* the main function to draw and move all sprites */
    if (this.init == false) {
      alert('error: object is not properly initialised');
      return false;
    }
    console.log(this.sprites, this.parser.result)
    if (this.parser.mode === 'single') {
      this.sprites[1].style.width = (this.parser.result[0] * 100) + "%";
    }
    if (this.parser.mode === 'multi') {
      let end = this.parser.result[0];
      let start = this.parser.result[1];
      var opt = this.parser.result[2];
      let rel;
      if (end <= start) {
        rel = 0;
      } else {
        rel = ((end - start) / end).toFixed(2);
      }
      this.sprites[1].style.width = (end * 100) + "%";
      this.sprites[2].style.width = (rel * 100) + "%";

      // now process additional options
      if (!opt.label) {
        this.sprites[2].innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
      } else {
        let label = opt.label.replace("%", (parseInt(100 * (end - start))) + ' %');
        this.sprites[2].innerHTML = label;
      }
      // check for custom sprite color 
      if (opt.color) {
        this.sprites[2].style.backgroundColor = opt.color;
      }
      // check for custom text color 
      if (opt.labelcolor) {
        this.sprites[2].style.color = opt.labelcolor;
      }

    }
  }
  this.show = () => {
    this.element.parentNode.style.display = 'inline';
  }
  this.hide = () => {
    this.element.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
  }
  this.val = (value) => {
    if (!value) {
      return this.element.value;
    } else {
      this.element.value = value;
      this.element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    }
  }

  this.rand = (maxVal = 1, minVal = 0, decVal = 2) => {
    let offVal;
    if (maxVal < minVal) {
      offVal = maxVal;
      maxVal = minVal;
      minVal = offVal;
    }
    offVal = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < decVal; i++) {
      offVal = offVal / 10;
    }
    let r = (Math.random()) * ((maxVal + offVal) - (minVal)) + minVal;
    if (r > maxVal) {
      r = maxVal;
    }
    let p = Math.pow(10, decVal);
    r = Math.floor(r * p) / p;
    return r;
  }
  this.initialize = () => {
    if (!this.init) {
      this.wrapper = this.element.parentNode;
      this.container = document.createElement('div');
      this.container.style.backgroundColor = this.defaults['bgcolor'];
      this.container.style.padding = `${this.defaults['padding']}px`;
      this.container.style.boxSizing = 'border-box';
      let relativeRad = (this.defaults['size'] / 2) + 'px';
      this.container.style.borderRadius = (relativeRad + ' ' + relativeRad + ' ' + relativeRad + ' ' + relativeRad);
      this.wrapper.appendChild(this.container);
      this.sprites = this.sprites.concat(this.container);
      this.mover = document.createElement('div');
      this.mover.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';

      this.mover.align = 'right';
      this.mover.style.width = '0%'
      this.mover.style.minWidth = (this.defaults['size'] - (this.defaults['padding'] * 2)) + 'px';
      this.mover.style.transition = parseInt(this.defaults['transition']) + 'ms';

      this.container.appendChild(this.mover);
      this.sprites = this.sprites.concat(this.mover);

      this.sprite = document.createElement('div');
      this.sprite.style.backgroundColor = this.defaults['color'];
      this.sprite.style.height = (this.defaults['size'] - (this.defaults['padding'] * 2)) + 'px';
      this.sprite.style.width = (this.defaults['size'] - (this.defaults['padding'] * 2)) + 'px';
      this.sprite.style.minWidth = (this.defaults['size'] - (this.defaults['padding'] * 2)) + 'px';
      this.sprite.style.display = 'block';
      this.sprite.style.boxSizing = 'border-box';
      this.sprite.className += " sprite-text";
      this.sprite.style.overflow = 'hidden';
      this.sprite.style.textAlign = 'center';
      this.sprite.style.top = (this.defaults['padding']);
      this.sprite.style.fontSize = parseInt(this.defaults['size'] - (this.defaults['padding'] * 3)) + 'px';
      this.sprite.style.padding = (this.defaults['padding'] / 2);
      relativeRad = (this.defaults['size'] / 2) + 'px';
      this.sprite.style.borderRadius = (relativeRad + ' ' + relativeRad + ' ' + relativeRad + ' ' + relativeRad);
      this.sprite.style.transition = parseInt(this.defaults['transition'] / 2) + 'ms';
      this.sprite.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';

      this.mover.appendChild(this.sprite);
      this.sprites = this.sprites.concat(this.sprite);
      this.init = true;
      return this.init;
    }
  }
  /* the part below finalizes the object setup  */
  this.initialize();
  return this;

};
/* end of of the plug-in code */


/* MyPlugin init */
window.MyObject_1 = new MyPlugin(document.getElementById("demo_input_1"), 'Object_1');
window.MyObject_2 = new MyPlugin(document.getElementById("demo_input_2"), 'Object_2');

// test if we can address sprites of the first object after creating a second object
MyObject_1.sprites[2].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
```

```css
.item-wrap {
  background-color: #999;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.demo_input {
  border: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: left
}

.item-text {
  border: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Avenir, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: left
}

.sprite-text {
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-wrap">
  <div class="item-text">
    <strong>Progress animation based on more values</strong><br>
    <small>The first value still sends the animation to a relative point between 0 and 1. 
 The second value streches the animated sprite to an offset starting point.</small><br>
  </div>
  <div id="demo_1_wrap" class="demo">
    <input id="demo_input_2" class="demo_input" type="text" value="0 , 0">
  </div>
  <p>
    <input type="button" name="show" value="show object" onClick="window.MyObject_2.show()">
    <input type="button" name="hide" value="hide object" onClick="window.MyObject_2.hide()">
    <input type="button" name="rand" value="set random" id="demo_2" onClick="window.processButton(this.id)">
    <input type="button" name="label" value="change color" id="color_2" onClick="processButton(this.id)">
    <input style="float:right" type="button" name="label" value="show label" id="label_2" onClick="window.processButton(this.id)">
  </p>
</div>
<div class="item-wrap">
  <div class="item-text">
    <strong>Progress animation based on a single input</strong><br>
    <small>The input value sends the animation to a relative point between 0 and 1. 
 Empty or wrong input does nothing, where 1 or higher shows the animation at 100%</small><br>
  </div>
  <div id="demo_1_wrap" class="demo">
    <input id="demo_input_1" class="demo_input" type="text" value="0" />
  </div>
  <p>
    <input type="button" name="show" value="show object" onClick="window.MyObject_1.show()">
    <input type="button" name="hide" value="hide object" onClick="window.MyObject_1.hide()">
    <input type="button" name="demo_" value="set random" id="demo_1" onClick="window.processButton(this.id)">
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also IE 11 shows a bunch of syntax problems - why don't you use common IIFEs ?
[(IIFEs on MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) and [your error is just a listener parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
My fixes to at least open your script where

```
Line# in the script / new content
138  this.draw = function (){
179  this.show = function (){
182  this.hide = function (){
185  this.val = function(value) {
194  this.rand = function(maxVal, minVal,decVal) {
would tell no support for default parameters - maybe check for undefined(?)
214  this.initialize = function (){
219      this.container.style.padding = "${this.defaults['padding']}px";
(wrong quotations here)
```

Comment: Sorry seems I used 1st script.

Comment: No - reported an error something about null -> listener, but checked code only - no HTML at all.